# csv filsize limit when importing with d3.csv

Tags: csv, import, crash, d3.js, size

Everything is in the title. Indeed, I cannot manage a correct import of a 92mb (more than 250000 rows) csv file with d3.csv : googlechrome returns the pop-up error message : inspected target crashed (the loading worked only once).

Would you have any idea ?

I'd be very grateful for any and all input

Comment: is this a programming question?  what language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This is really a limitation of the browser and not D3 itself. 92MB is a *very* large amount of data to load on a webpage and to process with Javascript and will *not* work in practice. You will have to reduce/summarize/subset the data in some way.